# URL decoding without changing +

Tags: java, http, decoding

I would to decode a URL but only for % encodings. I would like to leave non % encoding intact:

e.g.

```
url = 
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2FNews%2Fpolitics%2FMPs%2Brisk%2Blosing%2Bparliamentary%2Bimmunity%2B%2F-%2F1064%2F1395978%2F-%2Flvylki%2F-%2Findex.html

URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8") = http://www.domain.com/News/politics/MPs+risk+losing+parliamentary+immunity+/-/1064/1395978/-/lvylki/-/index.html
```

However if:

```
url = http://www.domain.com/News/politics/MPs+risk+losing+parliamentary+immunity+/-/1064/1395978/-/lvylki/-/index.html

URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8") = http://www.domain.com/News/politics/MPs risk losing parliamentary immunity /-/1064/1395978/-/lvylki/-/index.html
```

I would like:

```
URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8") = http://www.domain.com/News/politics/MPs+risk+losing+parliamentary+immunity+/-/1064/1395978/-/lvylki/-/index.html
```

How can I avoid `URLDecoder.decode()` from decoding + to " ". Generally I would like to leave non % encoded strings intact i.e. only convert % encodings.

Answer (score 1):

```
URLDecoder.decode(url.replaceAll("\\+", "%2B"))
```